# How to display only text formatted with TinyMCE 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have succesfully implemented the  full editor with TinyMCE plugin but i can't success to display the content, well formated (with tinyMce css) without editing mode.

Example:

**

> Here is what i can create in edition mode :

[image]

**

> Here is what i get in display mode :

[image]

As, you can see it's not same result at all...

So, how can i get exactly the same render outside of the editor mode ?

**

**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Fact, TinyMCE do not aplpy CSS if you dont activate it in  your Javascript with `tinymce.init`

So i did a small hack :

My HTML :

```
                 <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                        <div id="description_content">
                            <div class="text_description_content"><div class="mce-content-body"> <textarea class="tmpTextArea">{{project.description|raw }} </textarea></div></div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="toAppend" class="mce-content-body"></div> 
                    </div>
```

My JS :

```
//activate tinyMCE
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '.tmpTextArea',
            menubar: false,
            plugins: [
                'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
                'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
                'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code'
            ],
            toolbar: 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
            content_css: '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
        });
    //get what is inside the textarea editor
      var content = $('iframe').contents().find('#tinymce').contents();
//append it in a div
      $("#toAppend").append(content);
//disable edit 
      tinymce.activeEditor.hide();
//hide the textarea editor 
      $(".tmpTextArea").hide();
```

Hope this could help another one :)

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem too,
And i found 1 way to fix it: just enable **inline mode** and **readyonly mode**.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector : 'div.get_content_tinyMCE',
    inline: true,
    readonly: 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that you are using CSS in the editor but not using the same (or any) CSS when rendering the content outside the editor.

If you want things to look the same you need to use the same CSS both in and outside the editor.

Comment: Yeah that is the point. So how can i apply this CSS to this text ?
Maybe there is a javascript code who allow this ?
Because i'm using Cloud deployment

Comment: Are you wanting the external content to look like it does in the editor or the editor to look like the external content?

Comment: the external content to look like it does in the editor

Comment: So add that CSS that you are using in the editor to the page that is used to render the content outside the editor.

Comment: I don't know how to get the css. It's not in the TinyMCE Package or myabe i'm blind

Comment: Check your TinyMCE configuration for a `content_css` or `content_style` setting.  Based on your screenshot I am guessing you just copied the setup from the TinyMCE online examples and that uses `content_css`.